# problem facing in the installtion of xband8.6 using gfortran compiler

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I am trying to install xband8.6 using gfortran compiler. I am facing some issues that I am not able to get. Please have a look:

```
<xband>:  using xband path    /home/user/psharma/XBANDS/xband_8.6
<xband>:  OSTYPE = Linux
<xband>:  calling wish from   /usr/bin/wish
The symmetry program /home/user/psharma/XBANDS/xband_8.6/findsym_linux-gnu is created now.
rm -f *.o findsym  ../findsym_linux-gnu 
gfortran -O0 -g -Wall -fbounds-check -fbacktrace -c strdef.f
f951: Warning: Nonconforming tab character in column 1 of line 396 [-Wtabs]
f951: Warning: Nonconforming tab character in column 1 of line 397 [-Wtabs]
f951: Warning: Nonconforming tab character in column 1 of line 398 [-Wtabs]
f951: Warning: Nonconforming tab character in column 1 of line 690 [-Wtabs]
strdef.f:51:72:
Error: Type mismatch in argument ‘tau’ at (1); passed INTEGER(4) to REAL(8)
make: *** [makefile:23: strdef.o] Error 1
/bin/cp: cannot stat 'findsym': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access '/home/user/psharma/XBANDS/xband_8.6/findsym_linux-gnu': No such file or directory
```

I am trying to install xband8.6 using gfortran. I am not getting the error. I need some suggestion to install it.

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour] and read [ask] and [mcve]. This is a programming site, not a support site for various programs that someone created.  We can certainly give you an advice about the code error you see, but you have to show us the code the compiler is complaining about. Namely, `strdef.f`. Be prepared for an answer that will speak about changes to your Fortran code. For installation support, contact the author of the code or follow their instructions in the documentation.

Comment: Dear Expert,                                                                                                                           strdef.f is a large file. Here I am attaching the google drive link. Please have a look:                 https://drive.google.com/file/d/19cIojkzSIb7kOnhsgTOtE4r-xQ4ie8k2/view?usp=share_link

Comment: Please do not use external links. Isolate the necessary part and post it *directly into your question* using [edit]. Please note that the error message indicates the line where the error happens. However, we need more than just one line. We need the declarations of all entities that appear there and the general context. Please do take the [tour] and see the links I gave you.

Comment: The error is `strdef.f:51:72: Error: Type mismatch in argument ‘tau’ at (1); passed INTEGER(4) to REAL(8)`. It's either related to the type of the thing being called or the type of the value you're passing in; I'm going to guess that you've given `tau` the wrong type given what I know of areas of science that use that sort of thing (where tau is used for time constants), but I emphasise that *I don't know what you're doing* and *I could be quite wrong.* It could even be something silly like using `2` instead of `2.0`.

Comment: @DonalFellows Thank you so much for your sugesstion. This type of error I am getting when I am using gfortran, while with intel compiler problem being resolved.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.